# Como adicionar entradas num dicionário?

Tags: python, algoritmo, dicionário

Como adicionar entradas fornecidas por um usuário num dicionário? Por exemplo:

Entrada:

```
1 abcde
2 adecd
3 aaabb
```

O dicionário criado seria:

```
dicionario = {'abcde' : 1, 'adecd' : 2, 'aaabb' : 3}
```

ou

```
dicionario = {1 : 'abcde', 2 : 'adecd', 3 : 'aaabb'}
```

Existe alguma função semelhante a `append()` para se usar em dicinarios como se usa em lista? Digo isso por que como as entradas serão fornecidas pelo usuário, não dá pra ficar adicionando entrada por entrada (`dicionario['abcde'] = 1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar algo como:

```
entrada1 = input("Por favor insira um numero: ")
dicionario[entrada1] = 1
```

Comment: Como serão várias entradas, que eu não sei quantas serão exatamente (já que quem fará isso é o usuário) posso usar um loop para ir aceitando as entradas e criando o dicionário, correto?

Comment: Sim um mecanismo de controlo de entradas funciona bem.

Comment: Irei tentar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Para este exemplo que você está mostrando:

```
1 abcde  
2 adecd  
3 aaabb
```

Como se o usuário entrasse com os valores
 separados dessa maneira você pode fazer assim:

```
user_input = input('1 abcde')# simulando a entrada do usuário  
user_input = user_input.split(' ')  
user_notes[user_input[0]] = user_input[1];
```

Comment: Não entendi. Quem utilizar o programa deve fornecer as entradas da forma como mostrei, (1 abcde) e o programa deve criar um dicionário com essas entradas, utilizando cada item da entrada como chave/valor  (ou valor/chave), ou seja, as entradas devem ser inseridas num dicionário , da mesma forma como seria numa lista, onde cada entrada seria inserida na lista à medida em que fossem fornecidas, usando append(), por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

O mais prático para anexar um novo índice com um valor definido

```
dicionario['abcde'] = 1
```

Mas não entendi o que o impede de usar.

Você comentou:

> Digo isso por que como as entradas serão fornecidas pelo usuário, não
>   dá pra ficar adicionando entrada por entrada (dicionario['abcde'] =
>   1).

Então, outra forma de fazer seria com o método update()

```
dicionario.update({'abcde':1})
```

## Obtendo os dados via [raw cgi](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html)

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

for key in form:
    dicionario[key] = form[key]
```

## Obtendo os dados via request.POST

```
for key in request.POST:
    dicionario[key] = request.POST[key]
```

Comment: Preciso utilizar raw_input ou input para que o usuário do programa (não eu, que estou escrevendo) insira as entradas. É um exercício para criar um programa que receba notas de alunos 1, 2, 3, n alunos e depois compare as suas respostas com um gabarito. O usuário (tipo um professor) deve apenas inserir o "número" do aluno e as suas respostas, no formato 1 abcde, por exemplo. Por isso não posso fazer dessa maneira.

Comment: pois basta atribuir o valor do input a variável..

Comment: Irei tentar. Obrigado.

Comment: então acho que a sua questão é como iterar dados provindos do método GET/POST.. Adicionei exemplos..

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}
v = raw_input('valor: ')
d.update({len(d)+1:v})
```

Ou coloque num laço:

```
d = {}
while True:
    v = raw_input('valor')
    if v == 'Q':
        break
    d.update({len(d)+1:v})
print d
```